# I need help in building this Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, openssl

This error keeps bothering me

```
Recipes App
  displays 'Recipes for chocolate' when visiting the root (FAILED - 1)
  displays 'Recipes for chocolate' when visiting recipes/index (FAILED - 2)
  displays page for alternate search term (bread) (FAILED - 3)
  displays utf-8 chars in the title correctly (FAILED - 4)
  examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index
    displays table header row with 3 columns (FAILED - 5)
    displays table element that has a row with 3 columns (FAILED - 6)
    column 1 should have the thumbnail inside img tag inside a link tag (FAILED - 7)
    title should be inside a second column inside a link tag (FAILED - 8)

Failures:

  1) Recipes App displays 'Recipes for chocolate' when visiting the root
     Failure/Error: visit '/'

     OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
     # ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Recipes App displays 'Recipes for chocolate' when visiting recipes/index
     Failure/Error: visit '/recipes/index'

     OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
     # ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Recipes App displays page for alternate search term (bread)
     Failure/Error: visit "recipes/index?search=bread"

     OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
     # ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Recipes App displays utf-8 chars in the title correctly
     Failure/Error: visit "/recipes/index?search=amarula"

     OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
     # ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Recipes App examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index displays table header row 
with 3 columns
     Failure/Error: before { visit '/recipes/index' }

     OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
     # ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Recipes App examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index displays table element that has a row with 3 columns
     Failure/Error: before { visit '/recipes/index' }

     OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
     # ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Recipes App examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index column 1 should have the thumbnail inside img tag inside a link tag
     Failure/Error: before { visit '/recipes/index' }

     OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
     # ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) Recipes App examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index title should be inside a second column inside a link tag
     Failure/Error: before { visit '/recipes/index' }

     OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
     # ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 10.74 seconds (files took 1.55 seconds to load)
8 examples, 8 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:4 # Recipes App displays 'Recipes for chocolate' when visiting the 
root
rspec ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:9 # Recipes App displays 'Recipes for chocolate' when visiting recipes/index
rspec ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:14 # Recipes App displays page for alternate search term (bread)   
rspec ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:19 # Recipes App displays utf-8 chars in the title correctly       
rspec ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:27 # Recipes App examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index displays table header row with 3 columns
rspec ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:34 # Recipes App examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index displays table element that has a row with 3 columns
rspec ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:38 # Recipes App examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index column 1 should have the thumbnail inside img tag inside a link tag
rspec ./spec/recipes_app_spec.rb:42 # Recipes App examine page content (view) after visiting recipes/index title should be inside a second column inside a link tag
```

I am so tired of this , and I feel like dropping this outdated course.

[this is the source code](https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/recipe_puppy_bootstrap#assignment---recipe-hunter)

The application works fine in *rails s* command , and I am confident of that , just need to add a santize code , which I can do, but I don't know what is wrong with the damn rspec or OpenSSL maybe. I am using Ruby 2.6.6p146 , and have updated all the gems to the latest , stable , and compatible versions too.

I even tried the cacert.pem inside Railsinstaller , then to Environment variables (had Ruby 2.3.x before) method , then removed Railsinstaller and installed the new Ruby 2.6.x and 'default_options.update(verify: false) inside *recipe.rb*' method too.
Nothing works.

[This is my code below , and only files inside app and config have been changed , just drag and drop](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y-8SphwvkIMDr3y4bA3561czkvZfOzlo)

Comment: Is the spec trying to connect to an external service?

Comment: I haven't checked your code but these errors usually occur because the browser can't connect safely to an external API

Comment: There is a way to disable SSL verification, something you shouldn't do in production, but it might be ok to do in your testing environment. Have you researched that?

Comment: I am a beginner to ruby. And I have no clue about what you all are talking about. I am not sure about authentication and stuff , but if it works for now , I would be more than happy.

Comment: Make sense Ashvith. The answer of Rkarla looks good to me. Hope that works for you. Still good to look up what SSL is about on Wikipedia, it's good to know irrespectively from your Ruby level

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine if you do it for `test` environment

```
# Add to config/application.rb
if Rails.env.test?
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end
```

**NOTE:** **THIS IS SOMETHING I WON'T DO FOR** `production` **ENVIRONMENT**

Comment: I think this is for the newer Rails version, preferably 5 or 6. Rails 4 has this issue, especially with Railsinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Download the cacert.pem, and add a SSL path. It works fine.

https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Also, if possible, avoild Railsinstaller, and use Rubyinstaller.